# Получить путь до свойства объекта

Tags: javascript, typescript, объекты

Всем привет!
Что-то зашел в тупик, нужны свежие идеи)
Есть объект с вложенными структурами и у конечных свойств нужно получить путь до них.

```
const obj = {
 foo: {
  bar: 5,
 },
 zoo: {
  animal: {
   lion: 'sad'
  }
 }
 gain: true,
 list: [{
  a: 5,
 }]
}
```

На выходе надо получить объект вида:

```
const obj = {
 foo: {
  bar: 'foo.bar',
 },
 zoo: {
  animal: {
   lion: 'zoo.animal.lion'
  }
 }
 gain: 'gain',
 list: 'list[0].a'
}
```

Моя попытка( в массив еще не заходил **и варианта, что  в массиве не объект нет**, самое важное правильно обработать сильно вложенные объекты), нужно для правильного генерирования пропов для form-item:

```
const getFormItemProps = (formModel, mainKey) => {
  const formItemProps = {};

  Object.keys(formModel).forEach((key) => {
    if (typeof formModel[key] === 'object') {
      formItemProps[key] = getFormItemProps(formModel[key], key);
    } else {
      formItemProps[key] = `${mainKey ? `${mainKey}.` : ''}${key}`;
    }
  });

  return formItemProps;
};
```

Comment: Какой ещё такой тупик? Вы даже не опубликовали ваши попытки...

Comment: А что если в массиве ``obj.list`` будет несколько элементов? Любых, не только типа ``object``.

Comment: @ΝNL993 добавил последнюю попытку

Comment: @Neverm1ndo улучшил описание, такого варианта быть не может

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вам нужно что-то такое:

```js
const obj = {
 foo: {
  bar: 5,
 },
 zoo: {
  animal: {
   lion: 'sad'
  }
 },
 gain: true,
 list: [{
  a: 5,
 }, {
  b: 10,
 }, {
  c: 20
 }]
}

function genPaths(o, p) {
  p = (p ?? '')

  Object.keys(o).forEach(e => {
    if(Array.isArray(o[e])) {
      let arrPath = ''

      for (let i = 0; i < o[e].length; i++) {
        arrPath += `${e}[${i}].${Object.keys(o[e][i])}; `
      }

      o[e] = arrPath.slice(0, -1)
    } else if(typeof o[e] === 'object') {
      o[e] = genPaths(o[e], p + e + '.')
    } else {
      o[e] = p + e
    }
  })
  
  return o
}

console.log(genPaths(obj))
```

Также добавил в массив ещё парочку объектов чтобы было видно, что обрабатываются все элементы массива. Если в объекте (который в массиве) будет более одного ключа, тогда ключи будет отображаться через запятую.